# Laravel Autoprefixer not working within webpack

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5, sass

My `style.css` don't have css-prefix, when I run command `npm run production`. I'm using:

Laravel: 5.6.39 & Laravel-mix: 4.1.2

File `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css').options({
    postCss: [
       require('autoprefixer')({
          browsers: ['last 40 versions'],
             grid: true
          })
    ]
});
```

File `style.scss`

```
img {
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Output file `style.css`:

```
img{
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

How to add css-prefix to output file `style.css`?

Comment: Try using options first and then just `mix.css` as shown in file https://github.com/getkirby/getkirby.com/blob/c426896df51c44c42bee9bfd574076b670b3cd82/webpack.mix.js and see if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was fixed it. Just move origin `transform` before prefix.

```
img {
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

change to:

```
img {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   
}
```

and it work!